# Using ListBox to navigate a TextBox with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to move the following function `listView_SelectionChanged` away from code-behind and handle it directly inside my `ViewModel` (or directly as XAML). And I was hoping that someone might have a better idea on how to implement this.

The [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.aspx) contains Sections e.g. `[Secion1]` and to help navigate I have a [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.aspx) on the side of the `TextBox` that contains a list of all Sections. If you click on one of the Sections it will automatically jump to that part of the Text.

The code currently looks something like this:

**XAML**

```
ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Sections}" Name="listBox" 
                      SelectionMode="Single" Width="170" 
                      DisplayMemberPath="Section"
                      SelectionChanged="listView_SelectionChanged"/>

<TextBox Name="TextBox1" Text="{Binding Path=Source}"/>
```

**Model**

```
public class SourceData
{
    public SourceData()
    {
        Sections = new List<SectionData>();
    }

    public String Source { get; set; }

    public List<SectionData> Sections { get; set; }
}

public class SectionData
{
    public int Line { get; set; }        // Line of the Section
    public String Section { get; set; }  // Section name (e.g. [Section1]
}
```

**Code-behind**

```
private void listView_SelectionChanged(object sender,
                               System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var test = (SectionData)listBox.SelectedItem; // Get Information on the Section

    if (test.Line > 0 && test.Line <= TextBox1.LineCount) // Validate
    {
        TextBox1.ScrollToLine(test.Line - 1); // Scroll to Line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such situations I usually create an attached behavior (in your case it will be a behavior which will allow synchronizing textbox scrolled line), add property in ViewModel (`SourceData`) which will rule that attached behavior and bind behavior to this property.

Steps you should do in your case (I assume you know how to create an attached properties):

1) Create attached behavior `ScrolledLine` for textbox. It should support at least `one-way` binding. In attached property callback you will scroll textBox (to which behavior is attached) to the `line`. Below you will find a quick sample how to implement such a behavior.

2) Your `SourceData` should be extended with at least two properties: `SelectedSection` and `ScrolledLine`. `ScrolledLine` should be raising `PropertyChanged`. `SelectedSection` setter should change `ScrolledLine`:

```
private SectionData _selectedSection;
public SectionData SelectedSection
{
    get { return _selectedSection; }
    set 
    {
        _selectedSection = value;
        if (_selectedSection != null) SelectedLine = _selectedSection.Line;
    }
}
```

3) Bind your view to these two new properties:

`b` below is xml-namespace for your attached behavior from #1

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Sections}" SelectionMode="Single" Width="170" DisplayMemberPath="Section" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSection, Mode=TwoWay}" />

<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Source}" b:Behaviors.ScrolledLine="{Binding ScrolledLine}" />
```

4) Remove your `listView_SelectionChanged` event handler from view. Your view should not have any code except `InitializeComponent` from now on.

P.S.: Here is a sample how your attached behavior should look like:

```
public class b:Behaviors
{
    #region Attached DP registration

    public static int GetScrolledLine(TextBox obj)
    {
        return (int)obj.GetValue(ScrolledLineProperty);
    }

    public static void SetScrolledLine(TextBox obj, int value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ScrolledLineProperty, value);
    }

    #endregion

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrolledLineProperty=
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ScrolledLine", typeof(int), typeof(Behaviors), new PropertyMetadata(ScrolledLine_Callback));

    // This callback will be invoked when 'ScrolledLine' property will be changed. Here you should scroll a textbox
    private static void ScrolledLine_Callback(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textbox = (TextBox) source;

        int newLineValue = (int)e.NewValue;

        if (newLineValue > 0 && newLineValue <= textBox.LineCount) // Validate
            textbox.ScrollToLine(newLineValue - 1); // Scroll to Line
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Snowbear. Never used Attached Behaviors before (besides ACB), but with your guidance I got it up and working.

Comment: @Fuji, attached behaviors is invaluable to bring together views and viewModels in MVVM concept. There are a lot of cases just like this where AB may help a lot.

Comment: Yep, thanks again Snowboard, I am sure that there will be more situation where this will be useful as my application expands. Just a note on your example code you were missing new PropertyChangedCallback inside new PropertyMetadata.

Comment: @Fuji. `Snowboard` =))) There is a callback there - `new PropertyMetadata(ScrolledLine_Callback)`. Doesn't it work in this way? I haven't tested it, just typed it in out of my mind.

Comment: Haha sorry! was clearly day dreaming about Snowboarding! ;) I had to change it to => new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(ScrollToLineCallback)));